# Do I have to put #include <iostream> & #include "stdafx.h" in a header file?

Tags: c++

Do I have to put `#include <iostream>` & `#include "stdafx.h"` in a header file?

My header file only contains function prototypes.

Comment: what will happen if you compile your code? Try

Comment: ``stdafx.h`` is related to precompiled headers and should not be added to header files but only to .cpp files which are set to use precompiled headers (project settings). As for other "standard headers", there are actually 2 philosophies. Some recommend not to add "dependent includes" into header files. Some do it. In the end, that is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thnx, it was probably stupid question, but like I said I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to know stdafx.h is the default name of Visual Studio's pre-compiled header file, but you should put more information in your question. You should include stdafx.h in the *top* of every *source* file that uses the pre-compiled header. As for iostream, if you don't use anything from it in your header file, you don't need to include it.

Comment: Thnx for the quick feedback.